# .NET in container 100% CPU when memory limit reached

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, containers, swap

When running a .NET container on a openSUSE Tumbleweed (MicroOS) system with a set memory limit on the container (i.e. podman run --memory 32m xxx) and the program inside the container reaches the memory limit, it shortly after starts using almost all the available CPU and stays there until I manually kill the process in most cases.

Sometimes it is killed by OOM as expected, but most times it just keep running and burning CPU cycles (which makes it a "noisy neighbor")

My current theory is that it is somehow the Garbage Collector spending all that CPU trying to collect/free some RAM. It is somehow under the impression there is some more memory to get, whereas on other dist/kernel/os it is told "no - there is no more, no matter how hard you try".

- If I enable swap, the problem seems to go (mostly) away. The problem originates in Kubernetes where swap should be disabled on the node, but I reproduced it with podman to eleminate the complexity.
- ( I was first posting this problem in openSUSE community as it only seemed to happen on openSUSE Tumbleweed, but i later figured out it was probably because the MicroOS distro had swap disabled which was a "trigger" for the problem )
- I've also seen this problem on Java-based containers (i.e. Jenkins), but as far as I remember never i.e. Go applications which is why i expect it to be related somehow to Garbage collection methods used by .NET/Java.
- I've tried getting dumps (dotnet counters/gcdump) to figure out what it is doing and verify it is actually doing GC, but been unable to so far - It seems the process is in some locked state so it just hangs when trying to dump.
- Happens with both Server and Workstation GC mode
- .NET 5/6 should support cgroupsv2. I've had this problem since at least .NET 2.1 where cgroupsv2 wasn't supported, but even after waiting for .NET to support cgroupsv2 didn't make a difference. I've also tried disabling cgroupsv2 and used both runc, crun container runtimes, but no difference.

I found some articles discussing .NET/Containers/cgroupsv2 (https://mihai-albert.com/2022/02/13/out-of-memory-oom-in-kubernetes-part-2-the-oom-killer-and-application-runtime-implications/ and https://www.gresearch.co.uk/blog/article/taking-out-the-garbage-fixing-a-garbage-collection-issue-for-docker-on-net/ ) but didn't identify the golden solution in there.

I was considering adjusting some GC-properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector) but it's like going in blind without understanding what is going on.

I've made a simple .NET program that reproduces the problem - it basically just allocates more and more memory. https://github.com/DennisGlindhart/memoryworker (Dockerfile included which can be used to build the image - podman build -t xxx .)

Any hints pointers in the right direction of figuring out what is going on or/and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to draw a definitive conclusion. But if you are reaching your app's memory limit, the issue might be with the garbage collector.
Couple of things to look for in code

- You might be holding a reference to objects that are no longer needed.
- You are allocating too much to a Large Object Heap, which can lead to your issue. Objects larger than 85,000 bytes go to LOH.
- Maybe you are missing some Dispose call.

Here is an article describing how GC works (especially the part about Generations: small object heap and large object heap)
https://medium.com/@karol.rossa/garbage-collector-a019b9b0ff60

and about IDisposable
https://medium.com/@karol.rossa/we-have-already-covered-memory-management-topics-with-garbage-collection-and-implementing-ce00cdfb6d5c

Comment: Sorry, but my question is not about why an app might use a lot of memory, but that GC seems to spin out of control once it reaches or comes close to the limit. I was expecting the application to be OOM-killed or .NET throwing OutOfMemory-exceptions or something, but it doesn't.

Comment: Different things can trigger GC collection. If the trigger comes from OS, it can cause multiple GC runs if your app can't release enough memory.

Additionally, I don't know what the nature of your application is. The collection process can be time-consuming if many objects are allocated on LOH. 
The first thing to look for are arrays with reference-rich objects. During each collection, GC has to go over each object's references.

Greate tool for monitoring memory is dotMemory from JetBrains (it has free trial) https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/